# How do I keep a Timer alive in .net Maui when the app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, ios, maui, foreground-service, background-foreground

I'm hoping there is a cross-platform solution to keep a timer going when the app is backgrounded.

I'm trying to make a walking app for Android and iOS and the timer has to keep track of how long the user has walked and show that to the user anytime they bring the app out of the background.

I have Shiny 3.0, but according to Allan Ritchie, Shiny won't do that. Can anyone help? I have this code in the ViewModel.

```
 private void RunTimer()
 {
     _dispatcher.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), () =>
     {
         _dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
         {
             App.TotalRunningTime = DateTime.Now - App.CurrentWalkStartingDateTime - App.TotalPausedTime;

             var hours = App.TotalRunningTime.Hours;
             var minutes = App.TotalRunningTime.Minutes;
             var seconds = App.TotalRunningTime.Seconds;

             TimerText = String.Format("{0:00} : {1:00} : {2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);

             //     StepsCount = DependencyService.Get<IStepCounter>().Steps;
         });

         return TimerRunning;
     });
```

Comment: Short answer is - you don't.

Comment: requirements for running code in the bg vary a lot depending on the OS.  For your case saving a timestamp when the app is sent to the bg and then resuming when resuming when it is called to the fg might be best

Comment: Not only can't you keep a timer running, you don't need to. You simply need to store the date/time when the user started and then you can compute the elapsed time.  You don't need to keep computing the elapsed time when your app isn't on screen; the user can't see it

Comment: Thanks so much. That helps. I guess the question now is, what's best practice to sense that the Maui app is being backgrounded, and to save state to know what it's supposed to do when it comes back?